# Frequency spectrum of bremsstrahlung

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, particle-accelerators

I have tried to find a method to derive the spectrum of the emitted radiation of accelerated relativistic charged particles but I've never found such a method in any books. Does anyone know a method which predicts the frequency spectrum of such a particle? (I tried google many times but I only found graphs not derivations.)

Comment: See section 2.6 in [this paper](http://www.astro.unipd.it/franceschini/HighEnergy/2Bremsstrahlung.pdf)

Comment: A single particle will not emit a spectrum in the way you may be thinking.  Generally, a spectrum of emission caused by bremsstrahlung results from the accumulation of lots of particles with different energies and incident gyrophases undergoing this type of acceleration.

Comment: I have a knowledge about this. I edit my question to be accurate.